# Como reutilizar uma pthreads?

Tags: c, c++, thread, join, posix

Estou utilizando `pthread.h` e usando as seguintes funções:

```
//
// Cria A thread
//
thread_argsPP[contthreadsPP]        =   contthreadsPP;
pthread_create(&threadsPP[contthreadsPP], NULL,  ReceivePinPad, (void *)    &thread_argsPP[contthreadsPP]);

//
//  Inicia a thread
//
pthread_join(threadsPP[contthreadsPP], NULL);

//
//  Fecha a thread Recive
//
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

Mas após fechar a thread não consigo recriar ela, gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito para reutilizar uma pthread apos o `pthread_exit(NULL)`.

Comment: De que tipos são as variáveis `thread_argsPP`, `contthreadsPP` e `threadsPP`? Por favor cole a declaração delas pois isso é essencial para entender o seu problema. Ao que me parece você está perdendo a referência para algum dos objetos/estruturas quando não poderia.

Answer (score 0):

A função `pthread_exit`, espera todas as *Threads* serem encerradas para finalizar o sistema. Então seria a mesma coisa que usar um `exit`.

Mas caso queira reutilizar as threads, pode-se utilizar um contador para aguardar que elas terminem, pode-se utilizar um contador para saber quantas threads estão em execução.

```
int count;

void thread_call(void *data){
    ...
    count--;
}

void main(){
    ...
    for(...){ // cria as threads
        ...
        count++;
    }
    while(count); // espera as threads terminarem;
    for(...){ // re-instancia as threads
        ...
        count++;
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado,mas meu problema não e exatamente esse, mesmo depois da `pthread` terminada eu não consigo recria-la utilizando o `pthread_create` e `pthread_join`, queria saber se existe alguma forma que eu possa fazer isso, um exemplo: eu crio `pthread 1` mesmo ela chegando ao fim, ao `exit()`, eu não consigo criar ela novamente, s se criar a `pthread 2` com mesma função, somente uma nova

Comment: esta resposta está errada..."pthread_exit" termina a thread em que é chamada, como se fosse um comando "return"...outra coisa, aquele busy loop "while (count);" é *extremamente* desaconselhável...

Answer (score 0):

Não tem como você "reutilizar" a thread, o que você pode fazer é **recriar** a thread.

No programa que cria a thread:

```
for (;;)
{
  // testa algum criterio para nao (re)criar a thread
  if (...)
    break;

  // cria thread
  thread_argsPP[contthreadsPP] = contthreadsPP; // ??? isso faz sentido
  pthread_create(&threadsPP[contthreadsPP], NULL, ReceivePinPad, (void*)&thread_argsPP[contthreadsPP]);

  // espera a thread terminar
  pthread_join(threadsPP[contthreadsPP], NULL);
} // volta para proxima iteracao do for
```

Dentro da função ReceivePinPad

```
// pthread_detach(pthread_self()); // nao faz sentido aqui
// termina a thread (como se fosse um return da funcao ReceivePinPad)
pthread_exit(NULL);
```